# Django: admin save_model() ignores save()

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm using django-mptt and I'm using a queryset to filter the queryset.

Then I want to add the film to parent categories

- Media -----------------**(ADD HERE AFTER SAVE)**

  - Film -------------**(ADD HERE AFTER SAVE)**

    - Action -----(ADDING FILM HERE)
    - Horror -----(OR HERE, MAYBE)
    - ...
  - ...

.

```
class FilmAdmin(BlunneAdmin):

    # FILTER RESULTS TO SHOW IN ADMIN
    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == "categories":
        kwargs["queryset"] = Categ.objects.filter(parent__slug='films')
    return super(FilmAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)

    # ADD FILM TO PARENT'S CATEGORIES
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.save()
        obj.categs.add(Categ.objects.get(slug='media'))
        obj.categs.add(Categ.objects.get(slug='films'))
        obj.save()
```

How should I do it?

If I don't put the first save() I got this error:

**'Film' instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used.**

Comment: It works when you save before adding category relationships, but you don't want to have to save first? Is that your question?

Comment: It's saving on the first `obj.save()` but it's NOT saving the second time (doesn't show any error).

Comment: I think you might need to use `obj.save_m2m()` instead of `obj.save()` the second time.